# Rails How to create ajax star rating

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create some simple ajax rating using [rate it jquery](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm) .
I am able to see the stars and press them. But my form does not submit.

How do I submit the rating with ajax?

In my table I have two columns:

```
rating_score => The current score
ratings => The number of ratings which led to the score
```

My kategori show view:

```
<h1><%= @kategori.h2.force_encoding("UTF-8") %></h1>
<div id="konkurrancer"><%= render 'konkurrencer', :remote => true %></div>
```

My konkurrencer partial:

```
<div id="tabel">
  <table id="tabel1">
    <tr id="toptr">
      <td><%= sortable "name", "Navn" %></td>
    </tr>
    <% @konkurrancer.each do |vind| %>
      <tr class="thumbnail-item" onclick="window.open('<%= vind.tracking %>')">
        <td><%= truncate(vind.name.force_encoding("UTF-8"), :length => 45) %></td>
        <td>
          <div id="container">
            <%= render :partial => "rating", :remote => true, :locals => { :vind => vind } %>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <div id="pagenavi">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My ratings partial:

```
<%= form_for(:vind, :url => rate_path(vind.id), :remote => true, :html => { :method => 'put', :id => "rateform"}) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :ratings, :size => 1, :min => 1, :max => 6, :value => 1, :type => 'range', :step => '1', :id => "#{vind.id}" %>
<div class="rateit" id="rateit10b" data-rateit-backingfld="#<%= vind.id %>" data-rateit-resetable="false" ></div>
<% end %>
  <script type ="text/javascript">
     $('.rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
         var ri = $(this);

         //if the use pressed reset, it will get value: 0 (to be compatible with the HTML range control), we could check if e.type == 'reset', and then set the value to  null .
         var value = ri.rateit('value');
         var frmurl = ri.closest('form').attr('action'); //get the url from the form

         $.ajax({
             url: frmurl, //your server side script
             data: { ratings: value }, //our data
             type: 'PUT',
             success: function (data) {
                  //write here something when everything went ok

             },
             error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                 alert(msg); //something went wrong.
             }
         });
     });
 </script>
```

My rate.js:

```
$('#<%= @container %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'rating', locals: { konkurrancer: @konkurrancer })) %>');
```

My Controller:

```
class KonkurrancersController < ApplicationController
  def rate
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @container = "Konkurrancer"+@Konkurrancer.id.to_s

    @theme.rating_score += params[:rating].to_i
    @theme.ratings += 1
    @theme.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my rating in my browser. When I press gem Vind the params rating is send with ajax with the value 5. The problem is that I want it to send when pressed on the stars instead using the submit button.
[image]

My console when the form is submitted:

```
Started POST "/konkurrancers/rate/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-04 23:37:56 +0200

  Processing by KonkurrancersController#rate as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"3IqZ6IfvaFYQnVeMYu2a09PcCnm
VW52vaEp2KjfJ1g8=", "vind"=>{"rating"=>"6"}, "commit"=>"Gem Vind", "id"=>"12"}
  ←[1m←[35mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurr
ancers`
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`←
[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`
  ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
kurrancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`cached_slug` = '12') LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggab
le_type = 'Konkurrancer' AND slugs.name = '12' AND slugs.sequence = 1))
  ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
kurrancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`id` = 12) LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36mSlug Load (22.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `slugs`.* FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slu
gs`.sluggable_id = 12 AND `slugs`.sluggable_type = 'Konkurrancer') ORDER BY id D
ESC LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mAREL (14.0ms)←[0m  UPDATE `konkurrancers` SET `rating_score` = 17, `r
atings` = 5, `updated_at` = '2011-04-04 21:37:57' WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`id` =
12)
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (16.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
Rendered konkurrancers/_rating.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered konkurrancers/rate.js.erb (24.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 439ms (Views: 226.0ms | ActiveRecord: 55.0ms)
```

My html in view: http://pastie.org/1756195

Comment: How do I submit the star rating with ajax?

Comment: Can you narrow down what you mean by "the form does not submit"? Are you looking at the logs? Is the server getting a request? Did you hook up the plugin in jQuery(document).ready?

Comment: The form is only submitted when the button is pressed. What do you refer to when you say I should hook up the plugin in jQuery(document).read. I have included the jQuery script in my header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of the RateIt plugin. 
I have a small clue about Ruby On Rails, but I'll try to answer the question as good as possible.

The RateIt control doesn't submit automatically when something gets rated. You have to bind  to the `rated` event.

If your form is setup correctly, the following Javascript should work:

**AJAX submission:**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     jQuery('.rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
         var ri = jQuery(this);

         //disable voting...
         ri.rateit('readonly', true); 
         //add a span with the selected rating after the rateit plugin.
         ri.after('<span class="rating">' + ri.rateit('value') + '</span>');

         //if the use pressed reset, it will get value: 0 (to be compatible with the HTML range control), we could check if e.type == 'reset', and then set the value to  null .
         var frm = ri.closest('form');

         jQuery.ajax({
             url: frm.attr('action'), //your server side script
             data: frm.serialize(), //our data
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (data) {
                  //write here something when everything went ok

             },
             error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                 alert(msg); //something went wrong.
             }
         });
     });
 </script>
```

**non-AJAX submission**

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">
     jQuery('.rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
         jQuery(this).closest('form').submit();
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: My rating still not gets submitted. Here is some of my html output http://pastie.org/1750352

Comment: 1) You only need one time the javascript on the page, take it out of your loop. 2) Did you check with firebug/chrome developer, if something is sent?

Comment: The ajax does not work. I have removed it from the loop. I have updated my post with some more information. Here is my html http://pastie.org/1756195

Comment: First of all this code : <script type="text/javascript">
    var tooltipvalues = ['bad', 'poor', 'ok', 'good', 'super'];
    $("#rateit10b").bind('hover', function (event, value) { $(this).attr('title', tooltipvalues[value-1]); });
</script>     has to go down.

Comment: See my second comment, does it send something over the line?

Comment: I have moved it down put nothing happens. It only sends the rating when the form is submitted with the click on the button "Gem vind" http://pastie.org/1757765

Comment: I changed the script a bit, give it another try.

Comment: It does not work. The rating is only submitted when I press the submit button

Comment: if you can put the "working" sample online and put the link here I can help you much better.

Comment: Here is my app http://www.vinderhimlen.dk/vind-rejse-deltag-i-konkurrencer-om-rejser

Comment: I will haves look at it tomorrow.

Comment: 1) You have to learn javascript. Your js is a mess, you have many errors on the page, although possible, you use both prototype and jquery at the same time (because of that the $ function stopped working). You also have many scripts double on your page. 2) I've updated the example above, exchanging $ for jQuery. I hope this should work.

Comment: It works now when I press on the stars the form is submitted. :) How do I display the current rating and lock the form on submit?

Comment: I mean as Example http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm with a preset value but not with readonly

Comment: Because you are using a backing field, just add the value you want into the hidden field. <%= f.text_field ..... :value => 4, ..... %>

Comment: sorry for the delay, which version of jQuery are you using?